# how to change the table view cell image using binding with a model class property in mac app

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-bindings

I have a table view which contain table view cell and each cell containing image view, a progress spinner and a textfield and it shows syncing of each item.initially i show the progress spinner and hide the image view and they are dependent on a model class property "projectSyncStatus" bool type. i want that projectSyncStatus should bind with tableviewcell. if proectSyncStatus value will change the progressSpinner should hide and image view will display in mac app. and projectSyncStatus value change when syncing will complete.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a view based `NSTableView`, you can declare a NSView subclass that is used in your table view. This subclass based on `NSTableCellView` thus already has two outlets to NSImageView and NSTextField. Add your own IBOutlet to a second `NSImageView`.

Set the TableCellView prototype in your NSTableView in your xib up to be of your TableCellView class and add a second image view which you connect to the outlet you created above.

All that in detail is explained in [Apples documentation on NSTableView programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH1-SW1)